Issue with VNet Enterprise Policy not getting created for powerapps integration with azure services
I am trying to establish connectivity between powerapps with azure with enterprise policy powershell script i am using this https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/tree/master/powershell/enterprisePolicies#7-set-subnet-injection-for-an-environment but as soon as give newsubnetinjection.ps1 i am getting the below error, and am not able to link my policy with powerapps

WARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 2.
Linking of vnet policy did not start for environement Default-66673bbd-cec6-4964-b5ec-79b82ada2166
Error:

{
  "StatusCode": 404,
  "StatusDescription": null,
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Key": "Date",
      "Value": "Mon, 14 Oct 2024 09:25:17 GMT"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Cache-Control",
      "Value": "no-store, no-cache"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Strict-Transport-Security",
      "Value": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    },
    {
      "Key": "x-ms-islandgateway",
      "Value": "ga0000002"
    },
    {
      "Key": "x-ms-request-id",
      "Value": "southindia:6f2649fc-aba6-46a8-b725-a82832baefa4"
    },
    {
      "Key": "x-ms-correlation-request-id",
      "Value": "d9e7ddae-b5be-4fce-bd9b-aefcb92283c8"
    },
    {
      "Key": "x-ms-correlation-id",
      "Value": "d9e7ddae-b5be-4fce-bd9b-aefcb92283c8"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Server-Timing",
      "Value": "x-ms-igw-upstream-headers;dur=1529.9,x-ms-igw-req-overhead;dur=1.3"
    },
    {
      "Key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
      "Value": "nosniff"
    },
    {
      "Key": "x-ms-service-request-id",
      "Value": "bfcbbe2a-ac7d-4823-92c1-a061efbadf7a"
    },
    {
      "Key": "x-ms-activity-vector",
      "Value": "00"
    }
  ],
  "Error": {
    "code": "EnterprisePolicyCallFailed",
    "message": "The call to a dependent service failed. HttpStatusCode: 'NotFound' Error: '{\"error\":{\"namespace\":\"Quartz.ItemNotFound\",\"code\":\"ItemNotFound\",\"message\":\"Not able to get enterprise policy for policy id: 40d97138-88cf-4f1b-8d81-7c00d37a1a5d, tenant id: 66673bbd-cec6-4964-b5ec-79b82ada2166. Policy not found.\"}}'",
    "details": [
      "@{code=ItemNotFound; message=Not able to get enterprise policy for policy id: 40d97138-88cf-4f1b-8d81-7c00d37a1a5d, tenant id: 66673bbd-cec6-4964-b5ec-79b82ada2166. Policy not found.; detailUrlType=NotSpecified}"
    ],
    "detailUrlType": "NotSpecified"
  },
  "Message": "The call to a dependent service failed. HttpStatusCode: 'NotFound' Error: '{\"error\":{\"namespace\":\"Quartz.ItemNotFound\",\"code\":\"ItemNotFound\",\"message\":\"Not able to get enterprise policy for policy id: 40d97138-88cf-4f1b-8d81-7c00d37a1a5d, tenant id: 66673bbd-cec6-4964-b5ec-79b82ada2166. Policy not found.\"}}'",
  "Internal": {
    "Version": {
      "Major": 1,
      "Minor": 1,
      "Build": -1,
      "Revision": -1,
      "MajorRevision": -1,
      "MinorRevision": -1
    },
    "Content": {
      "Headers": "[Content-Length, System.String[]] [Content-Type, System.String[]]"
    },
    "StatusCode": 404,
    "ReasonPhrase": "Not Found",
    "Headers": [
      "[Date, System.String[]]",
      "[Cache-Control, System.String[]]",
      "[Strict-Transport-Security, System.String[]]",
      "[x-ms-islandgateway, System.String[]]",
      "[x-ms-request-id, System.String[]]",
      "[x-ms-correlation-request-id, System.String[]]",
      "[x-ms-correlation-id, System.String[]]",
      "[Server-Timing, System.String[]]",
      "[X-Content-Type-Options, System.String[]]",
      "[x-ms-service-request-id, System.String[]]",
      "[x-ms-activity-vector, System.String[]]"
    ],
    "TrailingHeaders": [],
    "RequestMessage": {
      "Version": "1.1",
      "VersionPolicy": 0,
      "Content": "System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent",
      "Method": "POST",
      "RequestUri": "https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/environments/Default-66673bbd-cec6-4964-b5ec-79b82ada2166/enterprisePolicies/NetworkInjection/link?&api-version=2019-10-01",
      "Headers": "[User-Agent, System.String[]] [Authorization, System.String[]] [Accept-Encoding, System.String[]]",
      "Properties": "",
      "Options": ""
    },
    "IsSuccessStatusCode": false
  }
}

Appreciate any help .
